# Xcode Internal error and no project opens

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Im on 10.6 and using xcode 3.2.6.  On xcode launch (however i launch) i get an xcode "internal error' popup telling me:

File:   /SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-1809/XcodeFoundation/Specifications/XCSpecification.m

Line:   448

Object:

Method: registerSpecificationProxiesFromPropertyListsInDirectory:recursively:inDomain:inBundle:

path should be a string, but it is nil

I can 'quit' or 'continue'.  Continue launches xcode.  The problem is that once open if i double click an .xcodeproj - nothing happens within xcode.  To open a project I have to manually go file->open and navigate to the file.

Google gives a couple of similar issues - including this one

http://lists.apple.com/archives/mac-games-dev/2011/Mar/threads.html#00001

And i've tried everything i can think of with no joy, (Including down grading to the xcode on the OS DVD).

Comment: Have you tried upgrading (XCode 4.1) as opposed to downgrading?  Or is 3.2.6 absolutely necessary?

Comment: I was mid project. I've upgraded now and solved the issues thanks. If you put as answer Im happy to Mark as accepted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it can be an issue with whatever particular version of Xcode that you have running.  It might be a good idea to get the latest and greatest to see if it's an issue with the Xcode software itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was just hitting this and fixed it by removing a dead symlink at:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins

[This thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/78792-Problem-with-XCode) tipped me off (although it wasn't Airplay in my case).

Comment: Interestingly I was using Airplay - and had tried the above without success... xcode 4 has sorted it out.